# Cython Sharing Extension Types: class

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I want to create a class in Cython which is readable in Python. Currently, my codes look like the ones below (of course they are not exactly the same, but the structure and organization of the codes are the same).

<del>As far as I understand, we cannot directly call Cython object from the Python, so I intended to make `TEST` class work as a wrapper, which can call faster Cython class.</del>


<del>However, I found a class object in `.pyx` cannot call a `cdef` function in Cythonized class in the same file, so `cdef class CYTEST` has another wrapper function `def func()`, which looks inefficient for me.</del>
(This paragraph in my original question turned out to be wrong)

I found we can declare the objects (such as `int`, `list`, and `object`) in a `.pxd` file, and we can read object in Cython class from Python class defined in `.pyx` file (in the example below, `print(self.cytest.somenum)`).

**Can we do the similar thing with Cythonized class? In the example, can we directly call `Cyfunc()` in `TEST` class?**

A part of `main.py`:

```
class MAIN:
    def __init__(self):
        cyobj1 = cyobj.CYTEST(self)
        cyobj2 = cyobj.CYTEST(self)
        cyobj1.func(3)
```

In `cyobj.pyx`

```
cdef class CYTEST:
    cdef object main
    cdef int somenum

    def __cinit__(self, object main):
        self.main = main
        self.somenum = 5
    def func(self, int num):
        return self.Cyfunc(num)

    cdef void Cyfunc(self, int num):
        print(num)
        self.main.cyobj2.Cyfunc(num+1) # what I want to do
```

`cyobj.pxd`:

```
cdef class CYTEST:
    cdef public object main
    cdef public int somenum
    cdef public void Cyfunc(self, int num)  # this doesn't work
```

[Official document](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-extension-types) does not have examples for my case.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. Did you try to call `CYTEST(MAIN())` in python? Only ` cdef `-functions/methods cannot be called from python - `cdef class`  is a different story.

Comment: @ead Oh, it works! Then, can we call `cdef` function in `cdef class` from another `cdef class`? In my example, I want to call `self.main.cyobj2.Cyfunc(num+1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.main.cyobj2.Cyfunc(num+1) # what I want to do
```

The issue is that it doesn't know that `self.main.cyobj2` is a `CYTEST` and thus it isn't possible to call `Cyfunc`.

The simplest option would be to cast it:

```
cdef CYTEST o = self.main.cyobj2
o.Cyfunc(num+1)
```

(You'll get a `TypeError` if the cast fails).

A second option would be to make `Cyfunc` a `cpdef` function so that it can be called without knowing the type in the normal Python manner.

A third option might be to make `MAIN` a `cdef class` too, and then specify the type of `cyobj1` and `cyobj2`, as well as `CYTEST.main`. However, this might cause problems with circular dependencies, so I'm not completely sure this is possible.

Comment: I tried the simplest approach, but I still get `AttributeError: 'cyobj.CYTEST' object has no attribute 'Cyfunc'` error.

Comment: The third approach works, but doesn't it slower than calling `cpdef` function?

Comment: Calling a `cpdef` function is slightly slower. A modified version of your example works for me, but there's quite a few small points I need to fix first - the version you show here really isn't an [mcve]. Without this it's difficult to know where you're going wrong

Comment: I forgot to modify my actual working code and your comment clears the point! Thanks. I forgot to remove definitions in `.pyx`.